# Microsoft bot framework publishing bot

Tags: facebook, frameworks, bots, publishing, reply

I created my bot and connected it with facebook. 
I have published my bot in "https://dev.botframework.com" but it is still in review stage for last 3 days. What is the use of this and how long it will take to publish.
I have made facebook messanger as public and people are able to add it in their contact but still it does not respond to them.

Comment: Did it upload for you?!

Comment: how much time did it take?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft, like Apple and other companies, review all bots submitted to the Bot STore in an effort to determine whether they are reliable, perform as expected, and are free of offensive material.

The estimated time to resolve this is one week. But it could take long.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Does this mean that even after adding in facebook contacts people cant sent messages until and unless it is reviewed.

Comment: Did it upload for you?! how much time did it take?

Answer (score 1):

Is your bot published now? I have created a bot and waiting for review with BOT team more than a week(approx 10 days). Please let me know any other available options. Thanks.

Comment: Did it upload for you?!

Comment: how much time did it take?

Answer (score 0):

Only Admin's and Tester's can test a FB app until it is reviewed by facebook.

Check out this issue on the [Microsoft Bot Framework repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/204) about similar issues.